# actionscript 3 unload library movie clip

Tags: load, movieclip

I developed a code that loads external .txt texts and internal (library) movie clips. The problem is that the loop is always loading new movie clips in between each other/above each other.

The problem is that this process is consuming a lot of memory RAM. I think I need to put a code to unload the movie clips, But i don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating instances of the movieclips dynamically in code? Just don't do it in a the enter frame event because that event fires every frame. If you need to unload a movieclip stage.removeChild(mc); should do the trick.